# Rails API always passes back HTML when called from an Angular service

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I have created a simple Rails API that returns a list of posts. I know it works as I can hit my localhost and see the results displayed as JSON just fine

e.g. **localhost:3000/1/posts/show_all.json**

When I try to hit this via my angular service:

```
    service.getAll = function() {
            return $http.get('/1/posts/show_all.json').success(function(posts) {
                console.log(posts);
            },function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
    };
```

I just get back a large amount of HTML but this HTML isn't a representation of the data - it just seems to be the index.html file. Here's my PostsController.rb and the routes.rb file:

```
class V1::PostsController < V1::ApplicationController

  respond_to :json

  def index
  end

  def create
    respond_with Post.create(posts_params)
  end

  def show
    respond_with Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  def show_all 
    @posts = Post.all
    render json: @posts
  end

  private
  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :content)
  end

end
```

Routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace "1", module: :v1 do
    resource :posts do
        get "show_all", to: "posts#show_all"
    end
  end
end
```

So do I need to expressively state that is should be returning json somewhere else, perhaps globally? I think the problem is quite simple as I'm sure I've encountered this once before.

Thanks

**EDIT**

Here's a screenshot of what I can get back by navigating to the http://localhost:3000/1/posts/show_all.json:

[image: JSON back]

**EDIT 2**

This is to demonstrate what the generic `$http` call should look like:

```
var req = {
 method: 'GET',
 url: 'http://localhost:3000/',
 headers: {
   'Content-Type': undefined
 },
 data: { test: 'test' }
}

$http(req).then(function(){...}, function(){...});
```

**EDIT**

This is the HTML that I'm getting back:

```
Posts:{"data":"<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html ng-app=\"app\">\n\t<head>\n\t\t<meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no\">\n\t\t<title>K24</title>\n\t</head>\n\n\t<body>\n\t\t<div class=\"container-fluid\" ui-view></div>\n\t\t<contact></contact>\n\t\t\n\t\t<link rel=\"shortcut icon\" href=\"images/favicon.ico\" type=\"image/x-icon\" />\n\t\t<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>\n\t\t<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css\">\t\n\t\t<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"css/styles.min.css\">\n\t\t<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css\">\n\n\t    <script src=\"https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0-rc.0/angular.min.js\"></script>\n\t\t<script src=\"https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0-rc.0/angular-animate.min.js\"></script>\n\t\t<script src=\"https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.14.3/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js\"></script>\n\t\t<script src=\"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js\"></script>\n\t    <script src=\"http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js\"></script>\n\t\t<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"js/main.js\"></script>\n\t</body>\n</html>","status":200,"config":{"method":"GET","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"url":"/1/posts/show_all.json","headers":{"Accept":"application/json"}},"statusText":"OK"}
```

To save you having to scroll all the way to the right here's probably the most relevant part:

```
"status":200,
"config":{
    "method":"GET",
    "transformRequest":[null],
    "transformResponse"[null],
    "url":"/1/posts/show_all.json",
    "headers":{
        "Accept":"application/json"
    }
 },
 "statusText":"OK"}
```

Comment: also - why the downvote? did i not present enough code or my own working out?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set right http headers in your angular request.

```
$http.get('/1/posts/show_all.json', headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json' , 'Content-Type' : 'application/json' }).success(function(posts)
```

Comment: You would only need to add headers in when you use the generic $http call, not the shortcut $http.get. Also, according to the angular site, the correct structure should be the above - see my second edit

Comment: Did anything happen when you tried by adding headers { 'Accept': 'application/json' , 'Content-Type' : 'application/json' } to your generic $http call.

Comment: I got the same response as I was getting - the same HTML error